# Pandas groupby sum is giving wrong output

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

My DataFrame:

```
State = ['CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'SR', 'SR', 'SR', 'SR']
County = ['UC', 'UC', 'DB', 'DB', 'DD', 'DD', 'DD', 'DD']
Count  = [100, 100, 150, 150, 200, 200, 200, 200]
df = pd.DataFrame({'State': State, 'County': County, 'Count' : Count})
```

Expected output:

```
 State  Count
0    CA    250
1    SR    200
```

This is what I am doing:

```
df_new = df.groupby(['State']).sum().reset_index()
```

This is what I am getting:

```
 State  Count
0    CA    500
1    SR    800
```

If County is repeated in State. it should ignore the duplicated entry. But, it is not doing it why?

Comment: Why do you think it should ignore duplicate entries? Why do you have duplicate counties in the first place?

Comment: Try `drop_duplicates()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `drop_duplicates` filtering the dataframe first then groupby and sum:

```
df.drop_duplicates(['State', 'County']).groupby('State').sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  State  Count
0    CA    250
1    SR    200
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it would be using lambda functions

```
df.groupby(['State']).apply(lambda x: x.groupby(['County']).Count.first().sum()).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
State   0
0   CA  250
1   SR  200
```

Hope this helps :)